# Limit record like ROWNUM in MS SQL server 2000

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, sql-server-2000

I want to know how to limit records in SQL Server 2000. In Oracle, I already wrote a SQL query like that.

```
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="myDSN">
    SELECT * from tbl where rownum <= 10
</cfquery>
```

In SQL Server 2000, I cannot limit any records within a SQL query. I know I can use **"maxrows"** of **cfquery** but I don't want CF to crawl the whole table first and limit it after all.

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server?  I'm a bit confused between the content of your question and the tags.

Comment: Yap, for mssql server 2000. I've mentioned it at title message.

Comment: FYI CF9 has strong SQL-level pagnition support in ORM for all DB it supports, including SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP(10) * 
  FROM tbl
```

For [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) (also [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/queries-limit.html), [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)):

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tbl
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It is worth noting `TOP` is not quite equivalent to `rownum` or `LIMIT`. You can use it to grab the first X records, but not arbitrary ranges ie rowNum X through y.  Unfortunately, a more convoluted query is required to achieve that in MS SQL 2000

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL Server you can use the Set Rowcount command to limit the number of rows returned

```
   SET ROWCOUNT 10
   SELECT * FROM TBL
```

Just remember to turn it back off afterwards by using

```
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: Nothing technically wrong with it. But I think TOP is preferable. It is simpler with less potential side effects.  However, kudos for the reminder to reset it afterward. It is easy to forget and wind up chasing your tail for a while ;)

Comment: Yes, I agree that `TOP` is probably the better solution. I put in the reminder to reset it afterward because **I** often forget that small step, and yes it can be frustrating trying to figure out what's going on afterward.